# is there any graphical JOLT spec generator exists?

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

is there any graphical JOLT spec generator exists?

I want a graphical JOLT spec generator. Is there any ?? I have seen http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/
what jolt have provided this is bit technical, is there anything that will help the new bie to use it without proper knowledge, means small knowledge should also works.